# iPhone 8 purchased through AT&T change to T-Mobile

Tags: iphone

I was able to purchase an iPhone 8 through my company with AT&T being the carrier.  I have since left the company and would like to use the phone with a T-Mobile plan.  When I put the T-Mobile SIM card in I receive the message Not Unlocked for that Network.  Any suggestions on how to make this work or can I use the phone w/AT&T only?

Answer (score 7):

Your original provider Controls the network lock status.

- https://www.att.com/deviceunlock/

Procedures differ per other providers, but for you, start at AT&T to check your lock status or request it be changed.

Comment: Network locks are often removable after the locked-to lcarrier (here, AT&T) has been paid for the purchase of the phone. How long that takes would depend on what sort of purchase your previous company made when it obtained the phone from AT&T.

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misunderstood your question, you're looking for a way to un-"simlock" your phone. There are many ways to do this:

- Make sure to check if you're sim-locked for a given period, or forever.
- Call AT&T provider and explain them the problem to normally get the network unlocked. It can differ with each provider.
- **(NOT RECOMMENDED!)** Try to google something like "unsimlock jailbreak ios" + your ios version to check if you can't just do it this way, if the provider does not answer or solve your problem...

Hope you solve your problem!
Léo

Comment: I certainly wouldn't recommend jailbreaking!

Comment: Sure ! Editing my message, sorry!